# Multiple default from address in ActionMailer Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Below is the normal format I copied from http://api.rubyonrails.org/

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

But what I want is to be able to have multiple address that it send form.

I tried to call a method, for example:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: address
  layout 'mailer'

  def address
     Apartment::Tenant.current_tenant == "org" ? "custom@email.com" : "from@example.com"
  end
end
```

When I call that method it returns

```
<ActionMailer::Base::NullMail:0x007fbefe0eb388>
```

and not the string that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: Apartment::Tenant.current_tenant == "org" ? "custom@email.com" : "from@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

Comment: This works, but I'm looking for a more elegant code if possible. nonetheless thanks!

Comment: is it possible to run a method before the default from line? I already tried before_action :initialize

Comment: address = Apartment::Tenant.current_tenant == "org" ? "custom@email.com" : "from@example.com"

And pass address to default_from